# jqGrid: Custom Search Reload Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to implement custom filter for my table.

For now, my table and inputs looks like this:
[image]

And following is my code

view.jsp

```
<div class="searchParent">
        <div class="noticeSearch">
            <p class="searchText">Search</p>
        </div>
        <div class="noticeDropDownOne">
            <select name="DropDownOne" id="DropDownOne">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="title">Title</option>
                <option value="writer">Writer</option>
                <option value="content">Content</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="noticeTextBoxOne">
            <input name="TextBoxOne" id="TextBoxOne" type="text" name="searchName">
        </div>
        <div class="noticeSearch">
            <p class="searchText">Period</p>
        </div>
        <div class="noticeDateTexBox">
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="dateFrom" class='searchDateOne' placeholder="2015-01-01">
        </div>
        <div class="noticeSearch">
            <p class="searchText">~</p>
        </div>
        <div class="noticeDateTexBox">
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="dateTo" class='searchDateTwo' placeholder="2015-01-01">
        </div>
        <div class="noticeSearchButton">
            <button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btnSearch">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <table id="noticeList"></table>
        <div id="pagerNotice"></div>
    </div>
```

(skip)

```
$("#noticeList").jqGrid({
                url : "<c:url value='/noti/getGrid'/>",
                colNames:['planId', 'Title', 'Date', 'Update Date', 'Writer', 'Subject', 'Hit'],
                colModel:[
                            {name:'noticeId', index:'noticeId', key: true,hidden: true},
                            {name:'notiTitle',index:'notiTitle', width:400,align:"center", resizable:false,
                             cellattr : function(rowId, value, rowObject){
                                 return "class='cursor_pointer'";
                             }},
                            {name:'notiCreateDate',index:'notiCreateDate', width:200,align:"center", resizable:false,
                             formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                                 return parseDatetoString(cellvalue, CONSTANT.YYYYMMDDFORMAT);
                             }},
                            {name:'notiUpdateDate',index:'notiUpdateDate', width:200,align:"center", resizable:false,
                             formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                                 var date = parseDatetoString(cellvalue, CONSTANT.YYYYMMDDFORMAT);
                                 var today = parseDatetoString(moment(), CONSTANT.YYYYMMDDFORMAT);
                                 if (date == today){
                                    return parseDatetoString(cellvalue, CONSTANT.HHMMSSFORMAT);
                                 } else {
                                    return (cellvalue == null ? '' : date);
                                 }
                             }},
                            {name:'notiWriter',index:'notiWriter', width:150,align:"center", resizable:false},
                            {name:'notiAttachment',index:'notiAttachment', width:100,align:"center", resizable:false},
                            {name:'notiHit',index:'notiHit', width:50,align:"center", resizable:false},
                ],
                rowNum : 10,
                multiselect: true,
                pager: '#pagerNotice',
                multiboxonly: true,
                sortname: 'notiCreateDate',
                sortorder: "desc",
                search: false,
                rownumbers : true,
```

(skip)

```
bindEvent : function(){
            $("#deleteRow").on('click', function(){
                $("#deletePopup").dialog("open");
            });

            $("#btnSearch").on('click', function(){
                var searchFilter = $("#TextBoxOne").val(), f;

                if (searchFilter.length === 0) {
                    $("#noticeList")[0].p.search = false;
                    $.extend($("#noticeList")[0].p.postData, {filters: ""});
                }
                f = {
                    groupOp : "OR",
                    rules : []
                };
                f.rules.push({
                    field : "notiTitle",
                    op : "cn",
                    data : searchFilter
                });
                $("#noticeList")[0].p.search = true;
                $.extend($("#noticeList")[0].p.postData, {
                    filters : JSON.stringify(f)
                });
                $("#noticeList").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page : 1}]);
            });
        },
```

Then when I type things in textbox and click search button,
[image]

I can see it grabs what I put in textbox and passes data through, but at the end, when it suppose to reload grid, it still shows all data.

FYI, btnSearch is button, TextBoxOne is textbox, noticeList is name of grid, and notiTitle is name of Title Column.

Please give me some help.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I followed Mr. Oleg's advice, put "loadonce : true" under my grid, and now it works!

Comment: Please include the information which jqGrid version you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7) in all your questions. I don't see in your code `loadonce: true` option. In the case your server code have to implement filtering of data (processing of `filters` parameter). Do you implemented this on the server side?

Comment: I am using Guriddo jqGrid ver 4.8.2.  I did not implement loadonce option.  And I just put loadonce : true under my grid and now it works.  Thank you so much Oleg.  It's third time you helped me this month lol.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that you have choice between *the server side* filtering of data and client side filtering. You current code don't use `loadonce: true` option. Thus it have to implement server side paging, sorting and filtering the data. jqGrid send `rows=10` parameter (based on `rowNum : 10`), `page=1` (the page number starting with 1), sorting parameters `sidx=notiCreateDate`, `sord=desc` (sortname: "notiCreateDate", sortorder: "desc") and optionally `filters` if you set it. The server have to filter the dataset, sort it and then return the page of resulting data (maximally 10 items).

I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` if the total number of data is less then 1000 rows or a little more as 1000. The server should return **all the data** at the first request. The data should be just sorted based on `sidx` and `sord` parameters. After that jqGrid will implement paging, sorting *and filtering* the data on the client side without any communication with the server. The current JavaScript engines are quickly enough and sorting, paging and filtering of for example 1000 or 20000 rows if data on the client side is more quickly as the round trip of simplest IP packet to the server. Thus the usage of `loadonce: true` makes your web site more quickly for the user.

About the choice of jqGrid fork. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork starting with renaming the old jqGrid to [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), changing the licence agreement and making Guriddo jqGrid JS commercial. See the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I provide free jqGrid under old MIT/ GPLv2 license without any mandatory . I just ask to contribute the development by donating via PayPal if it is possible. The development of both forks are more and more different and I will can't help the users of Guriddo jqGrid JS on the stackoverflow just because I don't know new functionality implemented in Guriddo jqGrid JS. On the other side *I improve free jqGrid permanently based on communication on the stackoverflow or on GitHub*. Thus free jqGrid became more and more user friendly and more easy to use. Free jqGrid in the current version 4.11.1 have more and more helpful features (see readmes to every published version and [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). The version 4.12.0 will be published this month. I'm preparing new site with documentation and code examples for free jqGrid and I plan permanently increase it.

You have to make the choice between free jqGrid and Guriddo jqGrid JS yourself. I just want to make you clear that the option exist and one have to make the choice sooner or later.